# video stream using gstreamer returns pixelated and with bad color jittering

Tags: udp, gstreamer, rtp

I started using a camera system that sends out RTP/AVP video stream, NTSC video format, CBR bitrate control and Progressive encoding.
I know it uses H264 encoding but I don't know the exact pipeline the stream is being transmitted with.
My main issues are:

1. when objects are moving in the frame they sometimes leave a trail of pixelated "afer image" of themselves like they haven't updated yet and it takes a few frames for it to fix itself.
2. Colors are all wrong in the frame, strong white objects have an aura of purple around them, and the main issue is I am getting color jitters all around the frame, like rainbow colors mixing around and generally disrupting the image.

I've had a few general issues with capturing the video but I finally managed to find a stable pipeline with minimal delay and freezes:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc uri=udp://234.1.1.1:10000 ! application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=H264, clock-rate=90000,payload=96  ! queue ! rtpjitterbuffer latency=500 mode=4 post-drop-messages=true ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264  max-threads=0 ! autovideosink
```

I have tried different decoding methods, and none seem to have a big difference between them.
I've also tried capturing the frame using opencv with gstreamer backend but got the same results.
I've tried capturing with VLC but the stream didn't capture anything.
My main thing i would like to fix is the color jittering, it is really disruptive and makes the image unbareable to look at.
If anyone has suggestions how to change the pipeline, or try other methods than gstreamer i would appreciate it

Comment: So it is either packet loss or your latency is set too low for the stream, discarding frames.

Comment: Is there any way to view/modify the encoding parameters of the camera? The ghosting could be the result of a high keyframe distance (set by the camera), any color issues can be because of mismatched color formats (try using `videoconvert` or explicitly set color format before depayloader), and glitching may be because of different packet sizes (change the `mtu` parameter in udpsrc). You also mentioned NTSC, so maybe try [deinterlacing](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/deinterlace/index.html?gi-language=c)?